# Can't validate XML file against XSD using notepad++

Tags: xml, validation, project

I have a project on my school on XML. I' m trying so many hours to validate this file
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1leUTabp0YbQUBj6jYtK5J9STDJGZBN5S/view?usp=sharing)
against this XSD file(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YJURb-nmkaciQlUSCsY3Q4zXkv8QFfzP/view?usp=sharing) using notepad++. When I validated it and use the command (xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schedule.xsd") I get this message: No error detected. When i validate without this command i get this (https://ibb.co/cr1F4CW).

Let me tell you that i have downloaded the XML plugin for notepad++  and my 2 files above are in the same folder.
I deleted and reinstalled the XML plugin but  that didn't work. Also i search on internet but i did not find something helpful.

Thank you in advance for your time :)

Comment: Please edit your post, remove links, and add textual XML and XSD to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following versions:

- Notepad++ v.7.91, 64-bit
- XML Tools plugin, v.3.1.0.1

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Schedule xmlns="http://www.somesite.com/schema/schedule"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.somesite.com/schema/schedule schedule.xsd">
    <Event>
        <Title>Artificial Intelligence</Title>
        <Lecture>
            <Day>Wednesday</Day>
            <Time>09-11</Time>
        </Lecture>
    </Event>
</Schedule>
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                      targetNamespace="http://www.somesite.com/schema/schedule"
                      xmlns="http://www.somesite.com/schema/schedule"
                      elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="Schedule">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Event"  maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Lecture">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="Day" type="xsd:string"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="Time" type="xsd:string"/>
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

**Notepad++**
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your immediate response. I uptated my npp and run the code. get the same results. thank u :)

Comment: @CaptainBo, glad to hear that you were able to resolve the issue. Please don't forget to mark the proposed solution as Answer.